# Windows 8.1 crashes periodically

Tags: windows-8.1, crash

Windows 8.1 keeps crashing about every half hour. This is the error report:

```
- System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power 
   [ Guid]  {331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4} 

   EventID 41 

   Version 3 

   Level 1 

   Task 63 

   Opcode 0 

   Keywords 0x8000000000000002 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2014-04-04T06:17:38.248857600Z 

   EventRecordID 6154 

   Correlation 

  - Execution 

   [ ProcessID]  4 
   [ ThreadID]  8 

   Channel System 

   Computer TianTian 

  - Security 

   [ UserID]  S-1-5-18 


- EventData 

  BugcheckCode 265 
  BugcheckParameter1 0xa3a01f58dcdda504 
  BugcheckParameter2 0xb3b72bdf2f5da53b 
  BugcheckParameter3 0xfffff803886a7000 
  BugcheckParameter4 0x3 
  SleepInProgress 0 
  PowerButtonTimestamp 0 
  BootAppStatus 0
```

Comment: The bug check code is `265` (`0x109` in hexadecimal), which translates to [`CRITICAL_STRUCTURE_CORRUPTION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557228%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): "This indicates that the kernel has detected critical kernel code or data corruption." In your case the 4th parameter is set to `0x3`, which means the corruption is related to "A processor global descriptor table (GDT)." The cause could be e.g. a misbehaving driver, or hardware corruption: "For example, the kernel code or data could have been stored in memory that failed."

Comment: I find it may be related to my Huawei android phone's driver - HiSuite. Plus, every time I start HiSuite, the outlook will crash.

Comment: Did you try [performing a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us) already? Also, do you get the same issue while in [safe mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-startup-settings-including-safe-mode)? Those steps should tell you whether the issue is related to some third party driver or software. You might want to check your memory modules for errors too, for example using [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/).

Comment: Did you try removing HiSuite ?

Comment: I think I have solved the problem. It is Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager. I have updated to the version 1.07 which is windows 8 hot fix. I have ran a whole day and haven.t meet a crash.